# Replacing/Overriding classes of the android-sdk

Tags: java, android, dex, apache-httpcomponents

I'm confused with the compilation under Android.

I've a library using those dependencies :

```
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') { 
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
//we need the org.apache.http.entity.ContentType class
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3')
```

My misunderstanding is that it compiles and *seems* to run properly, but I would expect a compilation error since :
**Android SDK contains many classes with exact same name as the classes in `httpcore`**

Here are my questions :

- Why is there no `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:...` during compilation ?
- How can I know which version of the duplicate classes is used at runtime ?

I'm using build tools 19 :

```
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    compileSdkVersion 15
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the official [Apache HttpClient port](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) for Android instead of the stock version

Comment: Thanks. I know that... but it don't really answer the question.